# Is there any limit on the members of queue in salesforce

Tags: queue

How many members/users we can add in a queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none other than the fact that you're limited to how many users/licenses you have in your org to include as members. This isn't specifically called out in the [Queue documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_queues.htm&type=5), but may inadvertently be in the [Chatter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_chatter_allocations.htm&type=5) one.

[image]

Considering added members to a Queue are stored in the same back-end object GroupMember, I think it's safe to say it's unlimited for Queues as well. You can quickly test and see by adding the public group "All Internal Users" to a queue and seeing no issues.

Important to note, that Queues also have the benefit of not having a limit to how many you can create which differentiates itself from the group limit above.

[image]